# @html.radiobuttonhow to set the true status?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.radiobuttonlist

I need to set the @html.radiobutton true status. I have two radiobutton. one is true state another one is false sate. how i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 RadioButtons in your view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "true")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "false")
```